# matplotlib syntax error when using python3 in a code that worked smoothly before

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am getting a syntax error when trying to `import matplotlib as plt`:

```
python3 sigClassCNN_tensor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sigClassCNN_tensor.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2480
    except ParseException, err:
```

I had this code working before.

Not sure what's changed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like it's mixing in python2 files ...

Comment: Make sure you have imported and updated all libraries to python3?

Comment: Please show a full (including the '#!' if you use one, otherwise the command used to invoke) code that generates this error.

Comment: So I have both Python2.7 and Python3.4 on my Centos machine. The code was run using a python3 compiler. From the error message, it looks like pyparsing.py was called using the python2.7 version. why would this be the case?

Comment: The original code was really long, include some of tensorflow stuff. But I am certain that it is the matplotlib package that's causing the issue. The code runs without error, if I comment it out.

Comment: I changed python2.7 folder name to Ppython2.7, and that solved my problem. l am not sure what's happending, but the code is now running.